# How to use bit masking to access six bits from buffer

Tags: c++

Let's says I have a buffer and I need to get 6 bits. Four bits from one element in the buffer and two bits from the next element. I think I know how to access the correct bits from each element but I'm not sure how to combine the bits. Here's some example code.

```
FILE * pFile;
long lSize;
unsigned char * buffer;
//int16_t * buffer;
size_t result;

pFile = fopen ( "TestFile.jpg" , "rb" );
if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

// obtain file size:
fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell (pFile);
//lSize = (ftell (pFile))/2;
rewind (pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
//buffer = (int16_t*) malloc (sizeof(int16_t)*lSize);
if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
//result = fread (buffer,2,lSize,pFile);
if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

/* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */

// I think this should get the last four bits of this element (buffer[i] >> 4) & 0xF)

// I think this should get the first two bits from the next element (buffer[i+1] & 0x3)

if (32 == ( ( (buffer[i] >> 4) & 0xF) & (buffer[i+1] & 0x3) ) ){
/*Do something.*/
}
```

Comment: Which 4 bits do you need from the first byte, and which 2 bits do you need from the second? After that, what order should they be in if they need to be concatenated?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this example the last four in the first byte and the first two in the second. Then for the concatenation the first byte comes first. So I get six continues bites from the buffer.

Comment: So, for the two bytes with bits: `abcdefgh ijklmnop`, you want a single byte which has the bits: `00efghij`? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which order you want to combine the bits in, but perhaps you want something like this:

```
unsigned char lastFourBits = (buffer[i] >> 4) & 0xF;         // 0000xxxx
unsigned char firstTwoBits = (buffer[i+1] & 0x3);            // 000000yy
unsigned char combined = (lastFourBits << 2) | firstTwoBits; // 00xxxxyy
```

or alternatively:

```
unsigned char combined = (firstTwoBits << 4) | lastFourBits; // 00yyxxxx
```

Comment: @MikelF I tend to agree, but I'm using the same naming convention that the questioner used in his code-comments, in an attempt to minimize confusion.  (the position referred to by "first bit" vs "last bit" being somewhat in the eye of the beholder)

Comment: Yea sorry about the poor choice of words. I'm trying to get six continues bits from two consecutive bytes. This is just so I can understand bit shifting and masking.

Comment: Hey so the "|" is whats combining the two values in this example right?

Comment: @Kahless Yes, the bitwise OR will act as addition in cases where there are no overlapping bits, like here.

Comment: O I see because if either bit is a one then it gets set to one. That makes sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The bit shift you are performing here `(buffer[i] >> 4)` is actually losing the 4 bits that you want. `(buffer[i] & 0xF)` will capture the low order four bits of the first byte. For the second byte, you want the two high order bits `(buffer[i+1] & 0xC0)` captures those bytes.

To concatenate:

`value = ((buffer[i] & 0x0F) << 2) + ((buffer[i+1] & 0xC0) >> 6);`

An example:  If the data stream is 0xABCD, or 1010 1011 1100 1101, this equation captures 101111.